# LWJGL+XCB Crashes randomly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, x11, xcb

I'm developing a 3D mode for an embedded software using LWJGL - i.e. OpenGL-ES.
I have to work with SWING elements, and also have to have a good enough framerate. So my solution was to get the X11 drawing surface from an AWT Canvas, use it to create the context and render directly onto that.

It seemed to work fine. It works on my PC and on the embedded device itself - and I've tested it for many hours.

However on several of my colleagues' PC's it just crashes immediately or almost immediately. The error most of the time is this:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting...
```

And it's true that I don't use XInitThreads, because none of the pre-compiled JNI files for LWJGL or AWT exposes that method.

The way I worked with threading so far is this:

```
public void lock() throws AWTException {
        int lock = JAWT_DrawingSurface_Lock(ds, ds.Lock());
        if ((lock & JAWT_LOCK_ERROR) != 0)
            throw new AWTException("JAWT_DrawingSurface_Lock() failed");
    }

    public void unlock() throws AWTException {
        JAWT_DrawingSurface_Unlock(ds, ds.Unlock());
    }
```

I basically call Lock() just before I do anything with the surface, and then Unlock() after I'm done.

This clearly wasn't enough, so I got those crashes.

I found a workaround here:
https://github.com/dunnololda/scage/blob/master/xdll.cpp

It fixes it like a charm. I couldn't make it to crash with this .so pre-loaded.

Problem: now my project manager is basically accusing me that the thing works without a hitch on both my PC and the embedded device - and asks me Why. He refuses to implement the fix or to let me write a JNI module and access the XInitThreads() - calling it a crutch. Because if it works on my PC - it should work everywhere, given that we all use the same PC with the same hardware and the same Debian distribution.

So my question is: WHY? Why does it work on my device and doesn't work on others? And what can I do to "fix" this?

Frankly, to my mind not calling the function that X-windowing system explicitly asks you to call in a multi-threaded app - is a stupid requirement.
But maybe at least good people here can explain me how and why it works?

Comment: Without `XInitThreads()`, the internal locking mechanism of XLib are no-ops. Only when that function is called, does XLib actually use a mutex for protecting its internal data. Does that already answer your question? (How: It sets some function pointers so that instead of no-ops, actual code is run for locking/unlocking; Why: well, no locking in multi-threaded apps leads to races leads to bugs.)

Comment: So basically you're saying that my machine is simply lucky that it doesn't run into threading bugs? Or could it be that some other application or subsystem enables XInitThreads and it somehow extends to the jar that I'm running?

Comment: "Luck" is always an option with threading bugs. I do not know if anything else calls `XInitThreads` for you. If you want to test that theory, you could try running your app under a debugger and set a breakpoint on `XInitThreads`. Is this even a threading bug? After re-reading your question, nothing says so explicitly. AFAIK, Swing requires you to do all interactions from some "main thread". Do you also do your LWJGL interactions from only that one thread? If so, this cannot be a threading bug...

Comment: Also, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6293929 says "To write Xlib multithread application you should use awtLock/awtUnlock methods instead of XInitThreads."